# How to Git commit as root on Linux?

Tags: linux, git

Sometime I have to modify configuration files such as the `/etc` repository created by etckeeper. So I do this:

```
sudo git commit -am "Modified this setting"
```

Unfortunately it will commit using the root credentials. One dirty alternative is

```
sudo git commit -am "Modified this setting" --author "John Doe <jdoe@doe.com>"
```

Is there another solution ?

One other example is my `/var/www` files set with `0640` and `root:www-data`. If I want to modify there files I have to do it from the `root` context. How can I do it with my own user account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This short script can be used to achieve what you want, provided you have git configured correctly as your regular user.  It accepts any and all arguments that `git commit` does except `--author` (which it automatically generates), and will automatically prompt you for a password, so you don't have to run it with `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=`git config --get user.name`
email=`git config --get user.email`

author="${name} <${email}>"

sudo git commit --author "$author" $@
```

It pulls your name and email out of your user's git configuration, composes the author info from that, and then invokes git to create the commit.  You can substitute `commit` for any other git sub-command that generates commits and accepts the `--author` argument.

Alternatively, clone the repository as your regular user (via a SSH clone, so for your `/var/www` example, it would be `git clone root@localhost:/var/www`), make your commits as your regular user, and then push them to the main repository.  This gives you a bit more freedom to manage your copy as you want, but requires that people can log in as root over ssh on the loopback interface.

Do note however that you want to be careful with using git directly with `etckeeper`, if you add or remove files `/etc/.etckeeper` has to be updated correctly.  That happens automatically if you do `etckeeper commit` (which unfortunately does not support arbitrary authorship of commits), but not if you just do `git commit`.

Answer (score 2):

To automatically include my non-root user's config files, I use the `bash` alias:

```
alias gsudo='sudo git -c "include.path='"${XDG_CONFIG_DIR:-$HOME/.config}/git/config\" -c \"include.path=$HOME/.gitconfig\""
```

Then I use `gsudo` instead of `git` to both:

- Run as root
- Have access to all non-root user git configuration

Check that the config is indeed being imported:

```
gsudo config --list --show-origin --includes | less
```

Comment: Works like a charm!